# How to split a single column into three columns in pandas (python)?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, split, dataframe, analytics

I have a huge data with a single column in which each row is in the format:

```
82283343~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers
```

I want to split the above column at tilde into three columns (`82283343`, `Electronics`, `Mobile Case & Covers`). I have written the following code:

```
df= df._id.map(lambda x: x.split('~'))
```

But this is not efficient at all and I end up closing the terminal. Is there a better way?

Comment: Check out this. What you need to do is "lazy load" the file - or more precisely create a generator method that breaks the file into manageable chunks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python

Answer (score 1):

I try doing some test and choose the best method.

The fastest one is creating list from column `_id` and split by native python `split('~')`:

```
df[['one', 'two', 'three']] = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('~') for x in df['_id'].tolist() ])
```

```
import pandas as pd

#test list
x =['82283344~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers', '82283346~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers', '82283343~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers']
#100000 lists
x = x * 100000

#create new df with column _id
df = pd.DataFrame({'_id': x })

print df.head()
                                         _id
0  82283344~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers
1  82283346~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers
2  82283343~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers
3  82283344~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers
4  82283346~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers
```

```
def DF(df):
    df[['one', 'two', 'three']] = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('~') for x in df['_id'].tolist() ])

def AP(df):
    df['one'] = df._id.apply(lambda x: x.split('~')[0])  
    df['two'] = df._id.apply(lambda x: x.split('~')[1])
    df['three'] = df._id.apply(lambda x: x.split('~')[2])

def EX(df):
    df[['one', 'two', 'three']] = df._id.str.split('~', expand=True)

def SP(df):
    df['one'] = df['_id'].str.split('~').str[0]
    df['two'] = df['_id'].str.split('~').str[1]
    df['three'] = df['_id'].str.split('~').str[2] 

DF(df)
print df.head()
AP(df)
print df.head()
EX(df)
print df.head()
SP(df)
print df.head()
```

4 times is repeating:

```
                                          _id       one          two  \
0  82283344~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers  82283344  Electronics   
1  82283346~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers  82283346  Electronics   
2  82283343~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers  82283343  Electronics   
3  82283344~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers  82283344  Electronics   
4  82283346~Electronics~Mobile Cases & Covers  82283346  Electronics   

                   three  
0  Mobile Cases & Covers  
1  Mobile Cases & Covers  
2  Mobile Cases & Covers  
3  Mobile Cases & Covers  
4  Mobile Cases & Covers
```

Timing:

```
In [125]: %timeit DF(df)
     ...: %timeit AP(df)
     ...: %timeit EX(df)
     ...: %timeit SP(df)
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 332 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 564 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 668 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1.09 s per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work fine to split a single column into 3 columns and save to same data frame again:

```py
df = df['_id'].str.split('~', 3, expand=True)
```

Please try this and let us know if you have any issues.